# Renaming files from blanc space between name to underscore with php

Tags: php, file-rename

i am trying to find a solution for the following problem:

I have two kinds of files in a folder of my webserver:

locked files__date_time.txt
locked files_date_time.txt

I would like to rename the files of the second type with the single underscore between "filename" and "date" like "locked files_date_time.txt" to "locked_files_date_time.txt" with a simple php-script.

This for i found a sample script, but its not working.

```
<?php
 $directory = '/daten/www/htdocs/files/locked/';
foreach (glob($directory."*locked files*") as $filename) {
$file = realpath($filename);
rename($file, str_replace("*locked files*","locked_files",$file));
}
?>
```

Script is geeting executed, without error, but nothing happens with the files.

What is wrong there?
Would be pleased about some support. Thanks very much in advance.

Greetz

Comment: `str_replace()` has no globbing/wildcard support.

Answer (score 0):

To update the file names this line needs to be updated:

Old:

```
str_replace("*locked files*","locked_files",$file));
```

New:

```
str_replace("locked__files","locked_files",$file));
```

To find the files that you are looking for this line needs to be updated:

Old:

```
foreach (glob($directory."*locked files*") as $filename) {
```

New:

```
foreach (glob($directory."*locked__files*") as $filename) {
```

That is looking for files that match what is between the double quotes.

```
<?php
$directory = '/daten/www/htdocs/files/locked/';
foreach (glob($directory."*locked files*") as $filename) {
    $file = realpath($filename);
    rename($file, str_replace("locked__files","locked_files",$file));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will solve your problem

```
rename($file, preg_replace("/locked files/","locked_files",$file));
```